# Error en api de google ads, funcion fromFile()

Tags: php, json, google-api, google-ads

Estoy intentando hacer una conexion a la api de google ads, descargue el proyecto de google-ads-php de github y al ejecutar el archivo GetCampaigns de los ejemplos recibo el error:

> PHP Warning: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/vt/credentials.json on line 1

Intenté cambiar la versión del repositorio *google-ads-php*, intente realizar la solicitud por curl, revise y cambie el archivo de credenciales descartando errores de sintaxis por completo verificado la ubicacion y los permisos adecuados, el codigo encuentra el archivo e intenta acceder a el pero indica una sintaxis erronea, sin embargo al intentar leer el archivo de credenciales con el código `$jsonContent = file_get_contents('credentials.json');` si puede leerlo.

Cabe mencionar que puedo ejecutar el archivo GetUserCredentials de manera correcta.

Aqui esta el código de GetCampaigns donde el error ocurre en la funcion `fromFile()`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright 2018 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

namespace Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations;

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

use GetOpt\GetOpt;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentNames;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V6\GoogleAdsClient;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V6\GoogleAdsClientBuilder;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V6\GoogleAdsException;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V6\GoogleAdsServerStreamDecorator;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V6\Errors\GoogleAdsError;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V6\Services\GoogleAdsRow;
use Google\ApiCore\ApiException;
```